# How to use more than two "AND" operations with case_when function in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements

I am attempting to create a new variable with case_when in R. Using age and score thresholds, I need to create a new descriptive variable with three possible outcomes. As an example:

1. IF age = 6 AND Score A >= 8, Strong
2. IF age = 6 AND Score A <8 AND Score B < 8, Some
3. IF age = 6 AND Score B >= 8, Weak

My issue is coming from outcome 2, where it seems as though my case_when function is only examining age and Score A rather than including age, Score A, and Score B in the conditional argument.

If I run the following code:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(New_Var = case_when(df$age==6 & df$ScoreA>=8 ~ "Strong",
                              df$age==6 & df$ScoreA<8 & df$ScoreB<8 ~"Some",
                              df$age==6 & df$ScoreB>=8 ~ "Weak"))
```

I'll get a case like this:

| Age | Score A | Score B | New_Var |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 4 | 10 | Some |

For "Some" to be the outcome, both Scores A and B need to be <8, but only Score A is in this case. Do I need to add an additional operator when I have more than two conditions that need to be met?

I've tried adding parentheses around the conditions, but I'm not sure what else to try to fix this issue.

Comment: In dplyr, you should not use $. You can replace all `x$y` inside the call to mutate with `y`, as in `(New_Var = age`

Comment: we cant reproduce your issue if you do not share the actual data and the exact code you are using and the exact output

Comment: Plese go through the tour and read some of stack overflow's basic tutorials, such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As @GuedesBF has suggested in first comment, removing every case of `df$` from your `case_when` function will probably fix it, but do post some sample data so we can test/replicate your problem if that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this,

```
age = c(6, 6, 6, 6)
ScoreA = c(1, 3, 6, 9)
ScoreB = c(2, 6, 8, 9)

df = data.frame(age, ScoreA, ScoreB, stringsAsFactors = FASLE)

df <- df %>% mutate(New_Var = case_when(age == 6 & ScoreA >= 8 ~ "Strong",
                                        age == 6 & ScoreA < 8 & ScoreB < 8 ~"Some",
                                        age == 6 & ScoreB >= 8 ~ "Weak"))
```

Output

```
> df
  age ScoreA ScoreB New_Var
1   6      1      2    Some
2   6      3      6    Some
3   6      6      8    Weak
4   6      9      9  Strong
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I figured out just now that the issue was that my score data in both columns was not coded as numeric in R (even though the data in the cells was numeric). By using as.numeric to recode my columns I was able to solve the issue of it seeming to only pass through the first condition of the "Some" code.